# Animating RecyclerView from Grid to Linear with MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, android-motionlayout, linearlayoutmanager

Can I animate transition of `RecyclerView` items from `Grid` layout to `Linear` (Horizontal) layout with use of `MotionLayout`?

I was unable to find any example of that.

My goal is to use `RecyclerView` in this `MotionLayout` based animated transition of custom grid:
[image]